# puppetlabs-apache redirectmatch to 404 is not working

Tags: puppet, apache2

guys!

I tried to return error 404 when accessing some directories on a vhost. Let's say we have http://bla.com/bla1, http://bla.com/bla2, http://bla.com/bla3, etc waiting to be redirected to 404.

I used the following:

```
redirectmatch_dest      =>      ['http://bla.com/bla1', ' http://bla.com/bla2', ' http://bla.com/bla3'],
redirectmatch_status   =>      ['404', '404', '404']
```

But when I access the links they don't return 404. Any suggestions what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

After testing a lot around `redirectmatch` I tried something different which is called `custom_fragment` which is simply importing single or lines of commands locating the at the end of the file. The second approach worked like a charm and returned successfully 404 to all subdirs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use `redirect_source` and `redirect_status` instead of `redirectmatch_dest` and `redirectmatch_status`

```
redirect_source => ['http://bla.com/bla1','http://bla.com/bla2','http://bla.com/bla3'],
redirect_status => ['404','404','404']
```

The `redirectmatch*` vhost parameters expect a regex. Also, your intention is to redirect **from** (`source`), not **to** (`dest`) the given URLs, hence you want `redirect_source`.